# Moduli Spaces of Manifolds vs Classifying Spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

In the literature, I've seen that people often conflate moduli spaces of manifolds (i.e. a space of submanifolds of a given manifold) with various classifying spaces of diffeomorphism groups. Could someone explain the usual procedure to go from some moduli space of manifolds to a classifying space, or vice versa.

In particular, I'm reading some of Randall-Wiliams' and Galatius' work, and at one point I read the statement "$\operatorname{BDiff(W, \partial W)}$, i.e. the moduli space of submanifolds...". If someone could explain even just this example, I'd appreciate it. This is found in the introduction of "Monoids of Moduli Spaces of Manifolds".

Comment: Ah, the Galatius, Madsen, Tillmann, Weiss paper gives details about this specific example. Notably, it comes from identifying the spaces of objects/morphisms with quotients of embedding spaces that have an action of certain diffeomorphism groups, which leads to being related to classifying spaces for the diffeomorphism group.

Comment: In their particular case their explicit model for $BDiff(W, \partial W)$ is a space of embeddings into an infinite-dimensional euclidean space (contractible by the Whitney embedding theorem), and the quotient of this space by the natural action of $Diff(W, \partial W)$ is interpreted as a space of manifolds diffeomorphic (rel boundary) to $W$, which I think is what *they* mean by "moduli space".

Comment: There is also [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3684449/relation-difference-between-moduli-spaces-and-classifying-spaces) which you may have already seen. My answer there just elaborates on my comment, but there is another answer that says something else.